# Control-m scheduling montly run

Tags: scheduling, control-m

i have a job that must run the first monday of each month then i need another few jobs to run the first Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday after the first monday, any idea how should i configure the jobs?

is possible to left a dummy job in "ended ok" status for 3 days to make sure the other jobs will run?

Comment: Use databand, or run it via a cronjob

Answer (score 1):

For the job on Monday, in the Scheduling tab enter 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in Month Days field, select AND and select Monday. This will give you a job that runs on the first Monday of each month.

For the other days, do the same as for the Monday but create a CONFCAL and add a shift value to it. Using the Tuesday job as an example, create a CONFCAL (pick a name for it) and in the Shift field select "Next Day". In the "Shift Num" field enter 1. This will then run on the Tuesday after the first Monday of the month.

Use the Forecast button (or run ctmrpln on the CM Server) to see the planned dates for submission.